# Openshift + socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

For many years I used to work with the dedicated server, but last week I decided to give a try to something new, so i found this website "openshift". I tried to do everything but i had no success to connect to socket.io.

As i was reading, not long time ago, openshift upgraded to v3 (whatever), so most examples i found do not work because they are old (for v2). As i guess `process.env.IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` deprecated in version 3 and there is no ip given in web console to connect except this url:
http://server-server-app.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com

I am trying to do something basic and here is my server code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports.app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080,
    ip   = process.env.IP   || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0';

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  //pass a http.Server instance
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

server.listen(port,ip);  //listen on port 8080
console.log('listen to :' + ip);
console.log('listen to :' + port);

here is my cient side code:
var Config = {

  "wsclientopts": { reconnection: false, 
                    reconnectionDelay: 2000,
                    reconnectionAttempts: 100,
                    secure: false
                  }
};

var connString = 'http://server-server-app.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com:8080';

socket = io.connect(connString, Config.wsclientopts);
socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log('connected')
});
```

all i get is :net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, so if someone can help me to get this thing up and running, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
var connString = 'http://server-server-app.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com:8080';
```

For a start, the external visible port is port 80, not port 8080. Port 8080 is only used if connecting to it internally from another service inside of the OpenShift cluster. The route you would have created maps external port 80 to internal port 8080 for you.

Rather than hardwire the hostname in the client, you should aim to have it passed back from the server by virtue of the server querying the `HTTP_HOST` header of the original inbound request.

Comment: Thank you, but when i do port 80 (and i tried) i get error:

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1245:19)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

Comment: Where are you changing it to port 80? I am not telling you to change ``process.env.PORT``, only change it in the client code, ie., ``connString``. I am presuming that client code is running in a browser outside of the OpenShift cluster.

Comment: Although the application inside of OpenShift will be listening on port 8080. The route created to expose the application outside of OpenShift will accept connections on port 80 at that generated hostname. The router in OpenShift will then connect through to port 8080 of the internal application and proxy the request.

Comment: IT WORKED :)))))))) Thank you :)